# Black dot in UITextField, instead of Placeholder text, when using Auto Layout in Xcode 9.2

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

After upgrading to Xcode 9.2, I have had a strange issue in Auto Layout with all the placeholders in my UITextFields.

[image]

Did anyone find a solution to this problem?

Comment: This issue continues to be in Run time.?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, that it does not occur in run time, only when viewing the storyboard. Thus making it a bit annoying to do A-B testing of screens.

Comment: you might have something in the `text` field. Check that

Comment: @YoungChul Please double check you textfields default texts.

Comment: There appears to be nothing there https://imgur.com/a/r4FGX, and it is a consistent problem throughout all UITextFields in the app.

Comment: this is new can you share storyboard screenshot with attribute inspector visible for your textfield, and as you said this is happening for all textfield so are you subclassing your textfields ?

Answer (score 0):

If using storyboard Just Uncheck secure text entry.

```
//or if using code 

youtTextFieldName.isSecureTextEntry = false
```